# Why does my Capistrano Deployment point to an old Commit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I finalized my last work on a git branch and merged it to the branch for my staging environment. But after my Capistrano Deployment Script finished i rubbed my eyes, because although my changes are pushed to Github my last Commit was completely ignored. They point is that even the remote branch points to the real last commit, but that is not recognised by capistrano for some reasons. Any Ideas?

Comment: How are your `:repo_url`, `:branch` and `:deploy_via` configured?

Comment: What is your evidence that Capistrano is using an old commit? Are you looking at the contents of `current/REVISION` on the server? If you are verifying by viewing the app in a browser, then perhaps the problem lies in your app not being restarted properly after the most recent deploy.

Comment: The branch I use is the master branch and the repo url leads to a private git. I do not use the deploy via. I looked at current/REVISION and at the app in the browser. Both shows that the last commits are ignored. Is it maybe possible that the problem relies on the merge? I had no conflicts at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem. There was a bad entry in the hosts file which leads to that strange behavior. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano 3 maintains a mirror of your Git repo on the server. It is stored alongside the `current`, `releases`, and `shared` directories in a directory called `repo`. Usually that means it is here:

```
/var/www/my_app_name/repo
```

If you are absolutely sure that the remote is up to date and yet Capistrano is not seeing it, then perhaps there is something wrong with this cached repo.

Try deleting the `repo` directory (or move it to a backup location) and deploying again. Capistrano will recreate it and hopefully pick up your new commits.